# Why Use FTP to copy files?

Tags: .net, ftp

I have a requirement to move large files from server to server in VB code, like in a Windows Service. My initial response was we need to use FTP classes in .NET because why would there be tools like Filezilla or CuteFTP if a simple file copy would do the trick.  But the more I think of it, I can't really come up with why FTP really is so important. Yet everyone seems to use it. What am I missing?

Comment: Define "a simple file copy."  If you mean that you can copy the file to something like a network share then, yes, FTP probably isn't necessary.  But if you don't have that protocol available, then FTP may be a viable alternative.  People use it because it's useful.

Comment: I meant the simple file copying methods, etc. available in VB.net. And I agree completely that FTP is useful and the way to go but a colleague didn't believe me..."it's just a file copy command, what's the big deal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the more I think of it, I can't really come up with why FTP really is so important.

FTP is a nearly universal file transfer protocol that allows the copying of files from one computer to a different computer on an internal network or on an external network like the Internet.

Copying David's comment. If you mean that you can copy the file to something like a network share them yes, FTP probably isn't necessary.

Adding my thought. If you have computers with different operating systems on a network, then FTP would be required.

Answer (score 2):

You can't file copy over all TCP networks.  FTP provides file transfer capability over any TCP network and implements error handling, retries, checkpoints, etc. that you would otherwise have to implement yourself.

If you implement your solution using Microsoft Windows Network or Active Directory as a dependency, Murphy demands that sooner or later you will have to use it to copy files between two servers that can't talk this way.  Use FTP ;-)